# Can denatured GFP show fluorescence?

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, protein-structure, sds-page

GFP ( green fluorescent protein) can show green fluorescence. And its fluorescence is due to the tri peptide chromophore which is given in below [image]I was wondering, can we observe fluorescence, if we denature it by boiling at 95 degree celsius? Say can we observe fluorescence band in SDS-PAGE?

I assume it can show some fluorescence as it is not due to any cofactors etc.

Answer (score 2):

According to [PDB (protein data bank — a repository for protein structures)](https://pdb101.rcsb.org/motm/42) the chromophore must be protected from interaction with water molecules to fluoresce.

> The chromophore is found right in the middle of the [protein], totally shielded from the surrounding environment. This shielding is essential for the fluorescence. The jostling water molecules would normally rob the chromophore of its energy once it absorbs a photon. But inside the protein, it is protected, releasing the energy instead as a slightly less energetic photon of light.

This means that denaturing the protein will result in quenching of the fluorescence<sup>1</sup>, so you are unlikely to see significant signal on a denaturing gel.  In fact, as WYSIWYG has pointed out, fluorescence has been used as a marker of renaturation of GFP<sup>1</sup>.

**Reference**:

1: [R.Y. Tsien (1998) The green fluorescent protein. Annual Review of Biochemistry 67, 509-544.](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/full/10.1146/annurev.biochem.67.1.509)

Comment: Additionally, there are biophysical studies on gfp folding in which increased fluorescence corresponds to folded state.

Comment: @WYSIWYG any reference if you give it would be appreciated

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you exchange the water in the gel with methanol or ethanol. Will these quench the fluorescence?

Comment: @Science123 check this out: https://www.pnas.org/content/109/44/17832